# Saving CLLocation error: Mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, swift, plist, cllocation, nskeyedarchiver

I have read the other related questions, but I am stuck.

I am trying to save the last known location into a plist for later use.

Here is the error message I am receiving:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Here is my code:

```
var plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist"))
var dataToStore = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(lastKnownLocation)
plist.setValue(dataToStore, forKey: "location")
```

The "lastKnownLocation" var is a CLLocation.  The "location" key in the plist is of type "data".  Could someone please assist and let me know how to do this (or how they do it if there is a better approach)?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
var plist: NSMutableDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path).mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plist.setValue(dataToStore, forKey: "location")
```

You can't call `setValue` on an `NSDictionary` as it is a mutating method and `NSDictionary` is immutable.

```
var plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist"))
```

Change `NSDictionary` in this to `NSMutableDictionary`.